# Remove string space, carriage return, line breaks, and tabs using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The question is fairly self-explanatory. I found a nice Java code block that does this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s*|\t|\r|\n");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
strReplaced = m.replaceAll("");
```

Basically removes string space, carriage return, line breaks, and tabs.

How can do the same thing using JavaScript? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

```
str = str.replace(/\s*|\t|\r|\n/gm, "")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
const test = "this\n is \t atest ";
const clean = test.replace(/[\n\r\t\s]+/g, "");
console.log(clean); // thisisatest
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String#replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll):

> The `replaceAll()` method returns a new string with all matches of a `pattern` replaced by a `replacement`. The pattern can be a string or a [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), and the replacement can be a string or a function to be called for each match.

```js
var str = 'Hello World!';
const replaced = str.replaceAll(new RegExp('\\s*|\t|\r|\n', 'g'), '');
console.log(replaced);
```

Or simply:

```js
var str = 'Hello World!';
const replaced = str.replaceAll(/\s*|\t|\r|\n/gm, '');
console.log(replaced);
```